# nativescript - couchbase cannot read property getDocument

Tags: typescript, nativescript, couchbase

I am trying to use couchbase with my nativescript app but I am getting an error when trying to enter a component that is using it.

this is my couchbase.servive.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Couchbase } from 'nativescript-couchbase';

@Injectable()
export class CouchbaseService {

    private database: any;

    public constructor() {
        this.database = new Couchbase("confusion");
    }

    public getDatabase() {
        return this.database;
    }

    public getDocument(docId: string) {
        return this.database.getDocument(docId);
    }

    public createDocument(data: any, docId: string) {
        return this.database.createDocument(data, docId);
    }

    public updateDocument(docId: string, data: any) {
        return this.database.updateDocument(docId, data);
    }

    public deleteDocument(docId: string) {
        return this.database.deleteDocument(docId);
    }
}
```

In my favorites.component.ts

I import the couchbase service and assing docId like this ( 
    docId: string = "favorites"; )

I am getting this error

JS: MANAGER ERROR: Cannot read property 'AndroidContext' of undefined
JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDocument' of undefined
JS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDocument' of undefined

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right plugin? You are suppose to use `nativescript-couchbase-plugin` as stated in the ReadMe. `nativescript-couchbase` is no longer maintained.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! Yes I was using the wrong plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nativescript-couchbase` plugin is no longer maintained. Please use `nativescript-couchbase-plugin` which is up to date.